# How to write a regex for any text except quotes or multiple hyphens?

Tags: asp.net, regex

Can anybody tell me how to write a regular expression for "no quotes (single or double) allowed and only single hyphens allowed"? For example, `"good"`, `'good'`, `good--looking` are not allowed (but `good-looking` is).

I need put this regex like following:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revProductName" runat="server" 
     ErrorMessage="Can not have &quot; or '." Font-Size="Smaller" 
     ControlToValidate="txtProductName" 
     ValidationExpression="^[^'|\"]*$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

The one I have is for double and single quotes. Now I need add multiple hyphens in there. I put like this `"^[^'|\"|--]*$"`, but it is not working.

Comment: Can you perform a search of quotes or double hyphens and if any of them are found, then implement some logic to precess?

Comment: What do you need the regexp to output?

Comment: sorry for the unclearness. I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?:-(?!-)|[^'"-]++)*$
```

should do.

```
^          # Start of string
(?:        # Either match...
 -(?!-)    # a hyphen, unless followed by another hyphen
|          # or
 [^'"-]++  # one or more characters except quotes/hyphen (possessive match)
)*         # any number of times
$          # End of string
```

Comment: What program do you use to align the expression and comments in the verbose mode? Or you just do it manually?

Comment: Hm, I was under the impression that ASP.NET supports possessive quantifiers. Did you escape the quote? Does it work with only one `+`?

Comment: Oops, if there is no possessive quantifier support, then it's a problem, since it'll lead to a heck of a lot of backtracking (because of nested `*` and `+`). I meant in case of stumbling into `'` or `"`. I think it's better then just to delete `++`. `*` will do the job. And maybe it's better to put `[^'"-]` before `-(?!-)` because it'll be appearing oftener then `-` in the text.

Comment: I removed one +, put like this  ValidationExpression='^(?:-(?!-)|[^'"-]+)*$'. Not working:(, regular string won't pass.

Comment: @ovgolovin: I know, I just wanted him to test whether the regex would then compile. Now since we know it still doesn't, it's not because of the possessive quantifier. I'm still guessing it's because Gaolai forgot to escape the quote.

Comment: @GaolaiPeng Very strange. I checked it in RegexCoach. It works as it should. Are you sure your string contains neither `'`, nor `"`, nor `--`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Oh, I think you are right guessing that Gaolai horgot to escape the quote. Otherwise the situations doesn't make any sense. :)

Comment: I put like ValidationExpression="^(?:-(?!-)|[^'&quot;-])*$", seems working now. Is this correct? Thanks guys.

Comment: I still not quite understand how that regex works? can anybody explain? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So, the regexp has to fail when ther is `'`, or `"`, or `--`.
So, the regexp should try this in every position, and if it's found, then fail:

```
^(?:(?!['"]|--).)*$
```

The idea is to consume all the line with `.`, but to check before using `.` each time that it not `'`, or `"`, or the beginning of `--`.

Also, I like the other answer very much. It uses a bit different approach. It consumes only non-`'"` symbols (`[^'"]`), and if it consumes `-`, it check if it's not followed by another `-`.

Also, there could be one more approach of searching for `'`, or `"`, or `--` in the string, and then failing the regex if they are found. I could be achieved by using regex conditional expression. But this flavor of regex engine doesn't seem to support such kind of conditions.

Comment: Good solution. Better than mine, I'd say.